# Need help with calculus II series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am working on a problem that my professor isn't really explaining well, so i decided to ask here.

The following is the question

$ f(x) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{\mathrm{(-1)}^{n+1}\mathrm{(x-5)}^{n}}{(n\mathrm{5}^{n})} $

I am asked to find the interval of convergence of the following

$f(x)$

$f'(x)$

$f''(x)$

$\int f(x) $

So for $ f(x) $ i used the ratio test $ (\frac{a_n+1}{a_n} )$ and got that -> $ 1 - \frac{x}{5} < 1 $ Is this the interval of convergence? I am totally clueless.

My main question was for $ f'(x) $ I have the first derivative as follows

$ f'(x) = \frac{\mathrm{(-1)}^{n+1}\mathrm{(x-5)}^{n-1}}{\mathrm{5}^{n}} $

Using the ratio $ (\frac{a_n+1}{a_n} )$ test on this one got me -> $ - \frac{x-5}{5} $ -> $ \frac{x}{5} - 1 $
But this will never be greater than 1.

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: First, you have ignored/dropped the absolute value from the ratio test.  Second, the ratio test can only tell you about the interior of the interval of convergence; that test is inconclusive at the endpoints, so you must use different techniques to check the endpoints.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what to do I guess. I tried to look at other problems but it seems this one is just different from any of the problems on our homework for Calc II. Something isn't making sense

Comment: Your question title mentions a series, but your question has no "\sum"s in it.

Comment: Sorry im not used to the formatting. I will fix that.

Answer (score 2):

For the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n$, where there is an $N$ such that $a_n \neq 0$ for all $n \geq N$, the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test) has you calculate
$$  L = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left|  \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|  $$
If $L < 1$, the series converges absolutely.  If $L = 1$ or the limit fails to exist, the test is inconclusive.  If $L > 1$ then the series is divergent.

In both of your examples, you have lost/ignored the absolute value.

For your first example, as I type this, you don't have a sum, but I will guess you meant
$$  f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (x-5)^n}{n 5^n}  \text{.}  $$
The numerator is only zero when $x = 5$, and that sum is easy to do, so we apply the ratio test to determine what happens when $x \neq 5$.  We compute \begin{align*}
L &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{\frac{(-1)^{(n+1)+1} (x-5)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1) 5^{(n+1)}}}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1} (x-5)^n}{n 5^n}} \right|  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)+1} (x-5)^{(n+1)}}{(n+1) 5^{(n+1)}} \cdot \frac{n 5^n}{(-1)^{n+1} (x-5)^n} \right|  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{(-1)^{(n+1)}(-1) (x-5)^{n}(x-5)}{(n+1) 5^{n}5} \cdot \frac{n 5^n}{(-1)^{n+1} (x-5)^n} \right|  \\
    &= \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{(-1) (x-5)}{(n+1) 5} \cdot \frac{n}{1} \right|  \\
    &= |(-1) (x-5)| \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left| \frac{n}{5(n+1)} \right|  \\
    &= \frac{1}{5} |x-5|  \text{.}
\end{align*}
The ratio test assures us the series converges if $L < 1$, so when \begin{align*}
\frac{1}{5} |x-5| &< 1  \\
|x-5| &< 5  \\
-5 < x-5 &< 5  \\
0 < x &< 10  \text{.}  
\end{align*}
The ratio test is inconclusive when $L = 1$, that is at $x = 0$ and $x = 10$, so we inspect those individually:

- $x = 0$:  \begin{align*}  
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (0-5)^n}{n 5^n}
      &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (-1)^n 5^n}{n 5^n}  \\
      &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{2n+1}}{n}  \\
      &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{-1}{n}  \\
      &= - \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n}  \text{,}
  \end{align*}
  which is minus a diverging [$p$-series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#P-series) (in particular, it is minus the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), which diverges).
- $x = 10$:  \begin{align*}  
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} (10-5)^n}{n 5^n}
      &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1} 5^n}{n 5^n}  \\
      &= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}  \text{,}
  \end{align*}
  which is an alternating series, whose terms monotonically decrease with limit zero.  By the [alternating series test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series#Alternating_series_test), this series converges.  (We could also recognize this as the [alternating harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Alternating_harmonic_series), which converges.)

Therefore, the interval of convergence of $f(x)$ is $(0,10]$.

You should be able to adapt the above to your other series.  If you have difficulties, ask in comments.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107677/discussion-on-answer-by-eric-towers-need-help-with-calculus-ii-series).

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\underbrace{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^n}{n5^n}}_{a_n}$$

By the ratio test, the series converges if the following holds:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{\frac{(-1)^{n+2}(x-5)^{n+1}}{(n+1)5^{n+1}}}{\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^n}{n5^n}}\right|=\frac{|x-5|}5\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac n{n+1}=\frac{|x-5|}5<1$$

Solve the inequality for $x$ to get the interval of convergence, $0<x<10$. Don't forget to check for convergence at the endpoints:

$$x=0\implies f(0)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(-5)^n}{n5^n}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{5^n}{n5^n}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n$$

$$x=10\implies f(10)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}5^n}{n5^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n$$

Do these series converge or diverge?

---

For the derivatives of $f$, you can differentiate the series as many times as needed. For instance,

$$f'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}n(x-5)^{n-1}}{n5^n}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^{n-1}}{5^n}$$

Then you can apply the same process as above to determine the interval where the series converges.

For the integral of $f$, first notice that $f(5)=0$, since this makes $(x-5)^n=0$ for all $n\ge1$. Then integrating $f$ gives the series

$$\int f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-5)^{n+1}}{n(n+1)5^n}$$